# Is this suffcient to show a sequence simply converges?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Does $f_n(x)$ simply converge?

$$
f_n(x)
=
\begin{cases}
\frac{1-e^{-n^2x^2}}{x} & \text{if } x \neq 0\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I said it doesn't **since $\forall x \in\mathbb R$, $f_n(x)\to\frac1x$ which is not a finite limit. Is it sufficient to show it doesn't simply converge?**

Comment: I'm having quite a bit of trouble parsing your question. However, if you fix an $x \ne 0$ and let $n \to \infty$, then $f_n(x)$ converges to the number $1/x$ with no problems. Why do you think $1/x$ is "not a finite limit"?

Answer (score 0):

If you showed that $f_n(x)\to 1/x$ for any $x\neq 0$ and see that $f_n(0)=0$ for each $n$, then this proves that 
the sequence $(f_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges pointwise to the function $f$ defined by 
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1/x&\mbox{ if }x\neq 0\\
0&\mbox{ if }x=0.
\end{cases}$$
The pointwise limit is not necessarily continuous.